# Apache Solr Search

Tags: apache, solr

I'm using Apache Solr for search.I import data from mysql table using data import handler.But when i use `q=KOHLI` insted of `q=lastname:KOHLI`,i didn't get any results.

Here is response for `q=lastname:KOHLI`

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
      "status": 0,
      "QTime": 1,
      "params": {
      "q": "lastname:KOHLI",
      "indent": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1427802213299"
    }
  },
  "response": {
     "numFound": 1,
     "start": 0,
     "docs": [
      {
        "lastname": "KOHLI",
        "town": "DELHI",
        "id": "2",
        "firstname": "VIRAT",
        "_version_": 1497158663291273200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

schema.xml:

```xml
<copyField source="firstname" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="lastname" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="town" dest="text"/>
<field name="firstname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lastname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="town" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`
```

Comment: *text* is your *defaultSearchField* ?

Comment: @alexf      yes,i want to search by firstname,lastname or town.

Comment: In your *solrConfig.xml*, you're not using a query parser?

Comment: @alexf         I don't know how to use query parser in solrConfig.xml,can you explain how it works?

Comment: You can read [that](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryParser). Add the snippet of your solrConfig.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify a field for the search, it searches the default search field. If you want to perform a search like that, you may create new field and copy all other fields that you want to make them a target for search to that field, then set it as default search field.

Here are some resources:

- [CopyField](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)
- [DefaultSearchField](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Default_Search_Field)

Comment: Never mind, If you find it the useful answer for you, sign it as an answer. @Nagendra

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a query parser? If yes, in your file *solrconfig.xml*, what is the query field that you are using inside your *requestHandler*? (*qf* parameter). If you don't have your field *lastname*, here it's a normal behaviour.

If you don't use a query parser, in your file *schema.xml*, what is your *defaultSearchField*?

Can you add snippets of your Solr's files?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not set default search field correctly. If you did not pass a field name in "q", it will search input to default field, which you set in config file for your project.

To set default field, you can do either way:

1. In your schema.xml, change `<defaultSearchField>id</defaultSearchField>`
   to `<defaultSearchField>lastname</defaultSearchField>`
2. Run with `q={!type=dismax qf=lastname}KOHLI` in your q (remove "q=" if in web port)

Reference:

See Query Type Short Form

https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.9.pdf

Hope it could help. Thank you.